# Facebook Graph get photos of public page pagination

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, pagination

I successfully managed to retrieve first 50 photos of a public page via FBGraph but can't make pagination work

```
1525666877712653?fields=albums{id,photos.limit(50){name,picture}}
```

Here's, for example, how I get them from CocaCola's public page. But how can I get 50 more?

Comment: Read this http://api-portal.anypoint.mulesoft.com/facebook/api/facebook-graph-api/docs/reference/pagination

Comment: i read that, thank you, but i cant figure out how to make this work with my filters.. i want to get only necessary fields to make the result as light as possible

Answer (score 1):

When doing

```
1525666877712653?fields=albums{id,photos.limit(50){name,picture}}
```

You will get:

```
{
  "data": [
     ... Endpoint data is here
  ],
  "paging": {
  "cursors": {
      "after": "MTE1NzQxNDAwODUwNA==", 
      "before": "MTU0MjU3NDQ3NzI3NQ=="
    }, 
  "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/1525666877712653/albums?fields=id,photos.limit(50){name,picture}&limit=25&after=MTE1NzQxNDAwODUwNA=="
}
```

And use the query you can get from the `next` field to get the results from 50 to 100. You will see that the filters are the same as in your initial query.